# API data bind into Excel with TableData officejs

Tags: excel, office-js

Binded API data into Excel with Office.TableData() from task pane and custom Ribbon command. Once Data binded into Excel then Table Design ribbon automatically appeared due to which previously selected custom tab out of focus so again have to choose custom tab in Excel using officejs.

I tried with below logic.

```
await Excel.run(async context=>{ 
await context.sync().then(()=>{
bindapidata();
const range=context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheets();
range.getRange().format.autoFitColumns();
return context.sync();
})
}
```

Expected output: Once Api data binded into Excel it should be maintain current selection of custom office Tab.

Actual output: Once Api data binded into Excel current selection out of focus then Table Design command appeared.

Comment: Any update please?

Comment: Team any comment please?